# Wix Code filter not working

Tags: velo

Im new to wix code. I created a simple database with a title field and some other fields as a test.

I created a text edit box so i can type in a search text, and a grid object so i can see the results.

I connect the grid to the data base and all the fields such as image, description etc.

Then i run the preview mode without typing anything, the grid shows all the table elements.

When i type into the search, even if i type something that is in the table, the grid is blank, seems the filter doesnt work??

Anybody knows why???

here is my code attached to the page

```
import wixData from "wix-data"

$w.onReady(function () {

});

export function iAddress_keyPress(event, $w) {
    filter($w('#iAddress').value);  // iAddress is the name of the input text box
}

function filter(title) {
    $w('#dataset1').setFilter(wixData.filter().contains('Title',title));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. This is problem:

```
contains('Title',title)
```

Title - it's "name" of the column. You should use "field name" from collection, it's displayed when you press "manage properties" on some column - it's actually id.

In your case, "title" is correct field name (as it's default)

Your example will work with this:

```
contains('title',title)
```